# htaccess rewrite rule url

Tags: html, .htaccess, web, url-rewriting, rule

I want to write htaccess rules where I can rewrite this

```
www.example.com/Project_Name/1/23 project.html?n=$1&p=$2&i=$3​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

I have this already, but the problem is that I have a file in /projects/projects.xml which gets rewritten as well when I call it with Ajax.

```
RewriteRule ^([\._\-a-zA-Z0-9]*)\/([0-9]*)\/([0-9]*)(.?)$ /project.html?n=$1&p=$2&i=$3 [NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` above the RewriteRule. Assuming projects.xml is an actual file, that should prevent rewriting.